# PHP application global variable

Tags: php, global-variables, application-variables

I want to store a global variable that exist as long as the application is running  and accessible from all the sessions. I tried $GLOBALS but it's not durable. It's temporary, I store the data and when I request the same code again, it says that this index not recognised.

Will I have to store my value in a file?

Edit :: this is a sample code that always print  'not set'

```
if(isset($GLOBALS['myindex']){
   echo 'set';
   echo $GLOBALS['myindex'];
}else{
   echo 'not set';
   $GLOBALS['myindex']='myValue';
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: $GLOBAL !== persistent.... if you need to persist data between requests,then you need to do so in a database or filesystem or session or a cache store like memcache or redis or APCu

Comment: @liquidflo

I edited the question . the code is up there . thank you  .

Comment: @MarkBaker
Thank you ,
is memcache persistant and accessible from all sessions ?

Comment: memcache is accessible from all threads.... it's only persistent as long as the memcache server is running (unless you configure it with a persistent back-end, which isn't standard)

Comment: what about apc  is it local and persistent ?

Comment: APCu is local (it runs in the webserver) and persistent (as long as you don't restart your webserver)..... googling a few of these options is faster than keeping asking

Comment: Thank you man and excuse me if i bothered you @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to go with Sessions:

Make sure you add session_start(); at the beginning of the application and it stays throughout the pages. Now you can assign the value to it. via :

```
 $_SESSION['yourkey'] = 'yourvalue'; // you can access it throughout the application
```